# Filter spark columns dynamically at run-time

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I need to create a spark filter statement that filters on a list of columns that is dynamically passed to it at run-time.

I have a SQL database table that has a column that stores a list of column names of a big data table. The big data table has been assigned to a spark dataset and I need to use this list of columns to check if any of dataset columns found in the list have data issues such as nulls or empty strings and return a count of the number of rows affected. The list of columns will be decided at run-time. The size of the list will vary.

```
public int returnRowCount (List<String> columnsAffected, Dataset<Row> dataset) {

    return dataset.filter(dataset.col(columnsAffected.get(0)).isNotNull() 
          || dataset.col(columnsAffected.get(0)).notEqual("") 
          || dataset.col(columnsAffected.get(1)).isNotNull() 
          || dataset.col(columnsAffected.get(1)).notEqual("") 
          || etc ).count();

}
```

I need the method to take any list of columns and any dataset. I want if any columns from list affected by null or empty string to be only counted once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create string filter expression and use that filter in `DataSets`

```
public long returnRowCount (List<String> columnsAffected, Dataset<Row> dataset) {
    String str = "";

    for (String col : columnsAffected){
        if (str != "")
            str = str + String.format("or %1$s is null or %1$s == '' ", col);
        else
            str = String.format(" %1$s is null or %1$s == '' ", col);
    }
    return dataset.filter(str).count();
}
```